# Noisy output from opamp comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, hysteresis

I built the following circuit to filter noisy pulses from a inductive tachometer pickup. The first opamp (U4D) acts as a peak detector. The second opamp (U4C) is a comparator which uses the output from the first as a reference voltage. The positive feedback on the comparator is for hysteresis.

[image]

I am getting a lot of noise on the output of the comparator. All of the technical articles I have read suggesting adding hysteresis (which I have already done) or using an actual comparator IC instead. Are there any other ways that I may be able to salvage this circuit?

[image]

Comment: You have forward feedback but it doesn't look like it is set up for reliable, predictable hysteresis to me since you are feeding your signal positive feedback to the same input. That means your hysteresis depends on your input level.

Comment: @DKNguyen, what is wrong with my hysteresis setup?

Comment: @DKNguyen, I am using the non-inverting setup shown here
https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/archive/2013/01/28/comparators-what-s-all-the-chatter

Comment: Have you just tried reducing the 300K?

Comment: Looks like you’ve built an oscillator. Replace R1 with two resistors, one to each rail.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I have tried reducing the resistor. Doing so does not help reduce the output noise.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, what do you mean by "one on each rail"

Comment: One from the input to the positive rail, one from the input to the negative rail.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

When comparator U4C output goes high (caused by the "A" signal from the first stage rising through the threshold set at "B") there is a reaction that lifts input "C" at U4D a little higher.

Lifting "C" higher causes the precision rectifiers output level (U4D) to rise and that, in turn causes the "B" signal to rise. That, in turn causes U4C's comparator output to switch back low.

At the start of the sentences above I said U4C output went high but, that caused a chain of events that ended up with it going low pretty much straight away afterwards.

Do you see the problem? The problem is that the actual input ("C") to U4D can be manipulated by the output of U4C and that is because that TACH1 input is fed via R4, a 10 kohm resistor. If that resistor wasn't there i.e. it were a short AND the output impedance of the input voltage at TACH1 were very low then this wouldn't happen.

Comment: I think I understand. I could possible solve this by adding an opamp buffer just to the right of C9? Is there another good way to isolate those two sections of the circuit?

Comment: I'd arrange U4C so that the hysteresis was not acting on the input signal but on the output of the peak detector. This inverts the output of course.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your slewrate is too slow to push the 2nd opamp out of the linear region. So the circuit oscillates.